# Multiply javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Why do I get 0 when I multiply a variable by 2 and assign the value to another variable? Basically, I'm trying to incrementally show/hide blocks every time I press the button. However, it works when I do count++ * 2.

Please see code below for reference.

```js
var count = 0,
    num = count * 2;

$('.load').on('click', function() {
   $('.blocks').show();
   $('.blocks').slice(num).hide();
    count++;
});

console.log(num); // num is = to 0
```

```css
.load {
    display: block;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

.blocks {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="load">Load this</button>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
```

Comment: 0 * 2 is still 0. So what did you expect? Place the log inside your click callback function.

Comment: Because the var you are multiplying by is equal to 0

Comment: When you first set `num` you have `count` set to 0, so `num`=0*2, or 0. You don't set `num` again.

Comment: i know 0 * 2 is =0. But after count++ should be 1 * 2 = 2. But instead I got 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// initial variable initialization
var count = 0,
num = count * 2;

$('.load').on('click', function() {
    $('.blocks').show();
    $('.blocks').slice(num).hide();
    // increment the count value
    count++;
    // re assign a new num value
    num = count * 2;
    console.log(num);
    // num is 0,2,4,6
});

console.log(num); // num is = to 0
```

Comment: @DyanDaw if found my answer useful and solves your problem. don't forget to accept it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

make num a simple function instead:

```
function num() { return count * 2; }
```